# How do I pass parameters to a salt state file?

Tags: python, salt-stack

I want to create a group and user using salt state files, but I do not know the group, gid, user, uid, sshkey until I need to execute the salt state file which I would like to pass in as parameters.

I have read about Pillar to create the variable. How do I create pillars before execution?

`/srv/salt/group.sls`:

```
{{ name }}:
  group.present:
    - gid: {{ gid }}
    - system: True
```

Command line:

```
salt 'SaltStack-01' state.sls group name=awesome gid=123456
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use Pillars to create "dictionaries" that you can reference into State files. I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but here's an example of what you can do:

1. `mkdir /srv/pillar/`
2. Create `/srv/pillar/groups.sls` and paste something like this into it:

   ```
   groups:
     first: 1234
     second: 5678
   ```

   These are names and GIDs of the groups you want to create.
3. Create `/srv/pillar/top.sls` so you can apply this pillar to your minions. This is very similar to a salt top file, so you can either apply it to all minions (`'*'`) or just the one (`'SaltStack-01'`):

   ```
   base:
     'hc01*':
       - groups
   ```

   To test that that has worked, you can run `salt '*' pillar.items` and you should find the `groups` pillar somewhere in the output.
4. Now, your `/srv/salt/group.sls` file should look like this:

   ```
   {% for group,gid in pillar.get('groups',{}).items() %}
   {{ group }}:
     group.present:
       - gid: {{ gid }}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   This is a for loop: `for` every `group` and `gid` in the pillar `groups`, do the rest. So basically, you can look at it as if the state file is running twice:

   ```
   first:
     group.present:
       - gid: 1234
   ```

   And then:

   ```
   second:
     group.present:
       - gid: 5678
   ```

This was incorporated from [this guide](https://salt.readthedocs.org/en/v2014.1.0rc1/topics/tutorials/pillar.html).

Answer (score 24):

If you really want to pass in the data on the command like you can also do it like this:

```
{{ pillar['name'] }}:
  group.present:
    - gid: {{ pillar['gid'] }}
    - system: True
```

Then on the command line you can pass in the data like this:

```
salt 'SaltStack-01' state.sls group pillar='{"name": "awesome", "gid": "123456"}'
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for when I asked the question all those years ago. The accepted answer is probably best practice tho. Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 5):

if you do not want use [Pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/config/pillar.html)
you can do as:

```
# /srv/salt/params.yaml

name: awesome
gid: 123456
```

and then:

```
# /srv/salt/groups.sls

{% import_yaml "params.yaml" as params %}

{{ params['name'] }}:
  group.present:
    - gid: {{ params['gid'] }}
    - system: True
```

more details:[doc](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html#gather-external-data)

Answer (score 1):

Another nice way to pass (incase you don't want to use pillars Nor create a file as other answers shows) - you can pass a local environment variable to salt and read it from within the sls file, **like this:**

Command:

```
MYVAR=world salt 'SaltStack-01' state.sls somesalt   # Note the env variable passed at the beginning
```

sls file:

```
# /srv/salt/somesalt.sls

foo:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        echo "hello {{ salt['environ.get']('MYVAR') }}"
```

Will print to stdout:

```
hello world
```

Another good thing to know is that the env variable also gets passed on to any included salt states as well.